# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'add_cog'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, tuples

I'm trying to make a discord music bot, but I'm getting this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
        cogs[i].setup(client)
      File "/home/runner/MOMOSNACK-BOT/music.py", line 48, in setup
        client.add_cog(music(client))
    AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'add_cog'`
```

I am following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHZlvRr9KxM&ab_channel=MaxA

I have tried replacing *client.add_cog(music(client))* with:

*client.add.cog(music(client))*

*bot.add_cog(music(client))*

*bot.add_cog(music(bot))*

Along with all the variations of capitalization, but none of these seemed to have fixed my problem. Thanks in advance for any help!

This is my *music.py*:

```
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    import youtube_dl
    
    class music(commands.Cog):
        def __init__(self, client):
            self.client = client
    
        @commands.command()
        async def join(self,ctx):
            if ctx.author.voice is None:
                await ctx.send("PLEASE JOIN A VC FIRST")
            voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
            if ctx.voice_channel is None:
                await voice_channel.connect()
            else:
                await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
    
        @commands.command()
        async def disconnect(self,ctx):
            await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
    
        @commands.command()
        async def play(self,ctx,url):
            ctx.voice_client.stop()
            FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
            YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
            vc = ctx.voice_client
    
            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
                info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
                url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
                source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
                vc.play(source)
    
        @commands.command()
        async def pause(self,ctx):
            await ctx.voice_client.pause()
            await ctx.send("PAUSED")
    
        @commands.command()
        async def resume(self,ctx):
            await ctx.voice_client.resume()
            await ctx.send("RESUMED")


    def setup(client):
        client.add_cog(music(client))
```

This is my *main.py* minus the bot's token. The bot also does some other things in the main.py but I don't think that was what messed it up:

```
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    import os
    import music
    
    cogs = [music]
    
    client = discord.Client(), commands.Bot(command_prefix='please ', intents = discord.Intents.all())

    for i in range(len(cogs)):
        cogs[i].setup(client)
      
    thankWords = ["Thank You", "Thank you", "thank you", "THANK YOU", "Thanks", "thanks", "THANKS", "Thx", "thx", "THX", "Tysm", "tysm", "TYSM"]

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
      print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
      if message.author == client.user:
        return

      msg = message.content
  
      if any(word in msg for word in thankWords):
        user = discord.utils.get(message.mentions)  
        await message.channel.send(user.mention + ' has received a **momosnack**!')

    client.run('[BOT TOKEN]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

In python, when you assign two comma-separated values to a variable, the variable will hold a tuple with those two values.

In your case, you are setting client to a tuple of `discord.Client` and `commands.Bot`. Judging by the fact that you are using commands, I would assume you would want to use only `commands.Bot`.

### Code

Replace

```py
client = discord.Client(), commands.Bot(command_prefix='please ', intents = discord.Intents.all())
```

with

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='please ', intents = discord.Intents.all())
```

### Reference

[Tuple packing/Unpacking](https://riptutorial.com/python/example/8400/packing-and-unpacking-tuples)